# How do I add a trendline to stock price data in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, statistics, trendline

I am attempting to make (i.e. calculate and plot) a trendline for stock price data in python.
So far, I have tried using numpy's polyfit function. However, it doesn't work for me, because I can't seem to define the y-axis... At this point, I imagine it is helpful to show the data that I'm dealing with:

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#get the price data for the stock
data = yf.download("AAPL","1990-01-01","2021-01-01")

#plot the data
plt.plot(data["Adj Close"])
plt.show()
```

Any ideas that could help me would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Using ployfit to fit a polynomial line (for example with degree 2 , a degree of 1 will be linear line)

```
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns

# create numpy array to fint regression line
x = np.arange(data["Adj Close"].size)
fit = np.polyfit(x, data["Adj Close"], deg=2)
fit_function = np.poly1d(fit)

sns.lineplot(data=data["Adj Close"]);
#Linear regression plot
sns.lineplot(x=data["Adj Close"].index ,y=fit_function(x))
```

[image]

Or you can get the trend of time series via STL decomposition

```
!pip install stldecompose

from stldecompose import decompose

decomp = decompose(data["Adj Close"].values)
trend = decomp.trend

sns.lineplot(data=data["Adj Close"]);
sns.lineplot(x=data["Adj Close"].index ,y=trend)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#get the price data for the stock
data = yf.download("AAPL","1990-01-01","2021-01-01")

data["index"]=data.index 
data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

data.index= data["index"]

#plot the data
plt.plot(data.index,data["Adj Close"])
plt.show()
```

Result is(Example is only for 2020 and 2021):

[image: Output of the code above]